# Use CSS media queries to pull out 2 containers in between other containers

Tags: css, media-queries

I need to use CSS media queries to pull out the 2nd and 4th box to the right. When the browser widens, box 2 and 4 needs to go to the right and box 2 needs to remain flush under box 1. The order of the boxes in required.

The solution I came up with is close, but when the text of box 2 is too long, it pushes box 3 down. It's important that box 3 remains flush under Box 1.

Here is an example in JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FJswg/

```
<html>
  <style>
    body {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    }
    div {
      padding:10px;
    }
    #box1 {
      color:#fff;
      background-color:#00f;
    }
    #box2 {
      background-color:#0f0;
    }
    #box3 {
      background-color:#f00;
    }
    #box4 {
      color:#fff;
      background-color:#000;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
      #box1 {
        float:left;
        clear:left;
        width:150px;
      }
      #box2 {
        margin-left:170px;
      }
      #box3 {
        float:left;
        clear:left;
        width:150px;
      }
      #box4 {
        margin-left:170px;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div id="box1">Box 1</div>
    <div id="box2">Box 2, Consectetur gentrify gluten-free fanny pack, bespoke enim ethical letterpress pitchfork ullamco pickled.</div>
    <div id="box3">Box 3</div>
    <div id="box4">Box 4, 8-bit mumblecore excepteur readymade single-origin coffee fingerstache mlkshk. Sint fanny pack raw denim quinoa. Ennui vero photo booth magna.</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Update

If I have to use JavaScript, is this the cleanest method? http://jsfiddle.net/FJswg/8/

```
var size = 0;
$(window).resize(function() {
    checkWidth();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    checkWidth();
});

function checkWidth() {
    var newWidth = $(window).width();
    var newSize = 0;
    if (newWidth >= 500) {
        newSize = 1;
    }
    if (newSize != size) {
        size = newSize;
        $moveElement = (size < 0) ? $("#box2") : $("#box3");
        $("#box1").after($moveElement);
    }
}?
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is using relative + absolute positioning. See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FJswg/6/) here.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
      #box1 {
        float:left;
        clear:left;
        width:150px;
      }
      #box2 {
        margin-left:170px;
      }
      #box3 {
        top: 50px;            
        clear:left;
        width:150px;
        position: absolute;
      }
      #box4 {
        margin-left:170px;
      }
```

You may also need to use javascript to dynamically set the `top` to `box1` height.

Comment: Interesting idea, but if I must resort to JavaScript, I think I'd simply rearrange the elements in the DOM (moving box 3 before box 2) so that no additional calculations would be required.